# How to "append" data to the destination list by making changes to the backend data of the source list

Tags: list, list-view, power-automate

I have two lists, one in the source sharepoint and the other in the destination sharepoint. The destination sharepoint has multiple tenants. Therefore, I can't overwrite its data. I want to append my data there by adding more rows to the backend data (Excel table) of the source sharepoint list. How can I do that?